# Nexus 10. The device cannot start. Code 10.

Tags: usb-drivers, samsung-nexus-10

I had some problem with my Nexus 10. Died on me and then came back from the dead. 
Since then it refuses to connect to my PC.
In the Device Manager I get "The device cannot start. Code 10."

I have uninstalled/reinstalled the USB and ADB drivers to no avail.

Even did a factory-reset to the tablet (was nothing real important on it).

I am totally stuck. I need to use it for development and it is totally useless to me like this.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to get the android sdk and install adb and the relevant Google drivers for your device. Uninstall any current ones you have. Not from the control panel but device manager

This guy had the same problem as yours but he had a i9250

http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/howto-install-google-sdk-adb-drivers-t1830108